# How to put text file into array and use it with methods

Tags: java, file, arraylist, methods

So I have a text file named "phone.txt" and I loaded it into an arraylist, the problem is now I don't know how to use that arraylist on my methods in the same class. Let's say on my method "optionP" that I want the customer to be able to search for a name in that arraylist and that person's info will be displayed, how would I do it? So far my code is like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Directory {

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public void run() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String initial;
        String department;
        int telNum;

        File inFile = new File("phone.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inFile);

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            Person list;
            lastName = in.next();
            firstName = in.next();
            initial = in.next();
            department = in.next();
            telNum = in.nextInt();
            list = new Person(lastName, firstName, initial, department, telNum);
            persons.add(list);
        }
        in.close();
        int i;
        i = 0;
        while (i < persons.size()) {
            System.out.println(persons.get(i).toString());
            i++;
        }

        char userInput = kbd.next().charAt(0);
        if (userInput == 'p' || userInput == 'P') {
            optionP();
        } else if (userInput == 'l' || userInput == 'L') {
            optionL();
        } else if (userInput == 'r' || userInput == 'R') {
            optionR();
        } else if (userInput == 'c' || userInput == 'C') {
            optionC();
        } else if (userInput == 'a' || userInput == 'A') {
            optionA();
        } else {
            optionD();
        }

    }

    public void optionP() {

    }

    public void optionL() {

    }

    public void optionR() {

    }

    public void optionC() {

    }

    public void optionA() {

    }

    public void optionD() {

    }

    public class Person {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String initial;
        String department;
        int telNum;

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String initial, String department, int telNum) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.initial = initial;
            this.department = department;
            this.telNum = telNum;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: so I am guessing that you did not write the above code.  Having the skill to write the above code would mean that you know how to iterate through an ArrayList

Comment: LOL I did write that code and I seriously tried using arraylist on my methods and it won't show anything, its just blank...

Comment: In optionP() how are you passing the name of the person that has to be searched?

Comment: show your effort so that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the file has data and that you are able to see the data when you print it on the console, if not you have to fix that first

Secondly if you wish to read from an arrayList

`for(Person p:persons){
//do what you want 
}`

Answer (score 0):

`OptionP` needs to go through the `ArrayList` and finds the corresponding result

Additionally, because you need to iterate the ArrayList, it's better to use `LinkedList` instead.

You may also need to add a `toString` method to describe the result.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Directory {

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Person> persons = new LinkedList<Person>();

    public void run() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String initial;
        String department;
        int telNum;

        File inFile = new File("/Users/zhaojing/Desktop/phone.txt");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inFile);

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            Person list;
            lastName = in.next();
            firstName = in.next();
            initial = in.next();
            department = in.next();
            telNum = in.nextInt();
            list = new Person(lastName, firstName, initial, department, telNum);
            persons.add(list);
        }
        in.close();
        int i;
        i = 0;
        while (i < persons.size()) {
            i++;
        }

        char userInput = kbd.next().charAt(0);
        if (userInput == 'p' || userInput == 'P') {
            optionP();


        } else if (userInput == 'l' || userInput == 'L') {
            optionL();
        } else if (userInput == 'r' || userInput == 'R') {
            optionR();
        } else if (userInput == 'c' || userInput == 'C') {
            optionC();
        } else if (userInput == 'a' || userInput == 'A') {
            optionA();
        } else {
            optionD();
        }

    }

    public Person optionP() {
        String userInputFirstName = kbd.next();

        for (Person p : persons) {
            if (Objects.equals(userInputFirstName, p.firstName)) {
                System.out.println(p.toString());
                return p;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void optionL() {

    }

    public void optionR() {

    }

    public void optionC() {

    }

    public void optionA() {

    }

    public void optionD() {

    }

    public class Person {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String initial;
        String department;
        int telNum;

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String initial, String department, int telNum) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.initial = initial;
            this.department = department;
            this.telNum = telNum;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "result: Person{" +
                    "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                    ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                    ", initial='" + initial + '\'' +
                    ", department='" + department + '\'' +
                    ", telNum=" + telNum +
                    '}';
        }
    }

}
```